# How can we read a json file only once for entire feature file in karate

Tags: json, karate

I am calling multiple json and js files in my feature file in background, which is required for every scenarion in my feature file.

- def test= read('classpath:testData/responseFiles/test.json')

problem is that, it is running/reading for each scenario. Is there something i can do, so that it read only once for feature file and can use for all scenarios. I am using 9.0.0 karate version

callonce is only working to call feature filen not json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the JSON file in a called feature and then use `callonce`.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks are the reply, if i am understanding it correctly, r u saying i should call a feature file using callonce which would read all the json files? is it?

Comment: @KarateCoder yes. something similar to this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file